# React Native Expo (Network Response Time Out Error)

Tags: react-native, expo

I Created a new project by using npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject

Everything is good, but when i run the app on my mobile (android) i have error.
i guess the problem in port how i can fix it?

Thanks everyone

I tried a lot and couldn't solve the problem
Thanks everyone

Comment: Are you sure your phone is connected to the same network? I get a timeout error when I'm attempted to connect to the server but the device isn't connected to the same network.

Comment: Yes i'm sure my laptop and my  phone are connected to the same network